# Is there a more efficient method than apply(), to check and replace row values in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I'm running the function below on my Dataframe, where if a date is the same as a date where there is an alert ('Y'), then the number in column 'tdelta' should be replaced by 250.

This is the original df:

```
   reset category       date     id  group  tdelta  tdelta reverse
6      N      low 2021-06-23  16860    2.0    33.0             0.0
5      Y      low 2021-05-21  16860    2.0     0.0           -33.0
10     N   medium 2020-12-06   1111    1.0    29.0             0.0
1      Y      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0     0.0             0.0
2      N      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0     0.0             0.0
8      Y   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0     0.0           -29.0
9      N   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0     0.0           -29.0
4      N      low 2019-11-08  16860    0.0    65.0             0.0
3      N      low 2019-09-07  16860    0.0     3.0           -62.0
7      N   medium 2019-09-04   1111    0.0     0.0             0.0
```

This is the code and resulting output:

```
def format(row):

    r_dates = df[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['reset'] == 'Y')]['date']
    r_dates = r_dates.tolist()

    if row['date'] in r_dates:
        val = 250
    else:
        val = row['tdelta']
    
    return val


df['tdelta'] = df.apply(format, axis =1)

print(df)

   reset category       date     id  group  tdelta  tdelta reverse
6      N      low 2021-06-23  16860    2.0    33.0             0.0
5      Y      low 2021-05-21  16860    2.0   250.0           -33.0
10     N   medium 2020-12-06   1111    1.0    29.0             0.0
1      Y      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0   250.0             0.0
2      N      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0   250.0             0.0
8      Y   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0   250.0           -29.0
9      N   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0   250.0           -29.0
4      N      low 2019-11-08  16860    0.0    65.0             0.0
3      N      low 2019-09-07  16860    0.0     3.0           -62.0
7      N   medium 2019-09-04   1111    0.0     0.0             0.0
0      N      low 2019-09-04  16860    0.0     0.0           -65.0
```

However, when I apply this non a much larger dataset (approx. 200k rows), then it seems to take a very long time. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient practical way of accomplishing the above code.

EDIT:

I have changed some of the ids in column "id" to reflect what happens with different ids.

The id column must also be taken into account as in the much larger dataset (with different ids in the id column), there are reset dates unique for those ids.

Therefore, I would need to calculate all the resets that are "Y" for that id.

The issue is there will be other ids that may fall into the same date as an alert for another id, however, those shouldn't change, as shown in the third row (index 10), where the date is the same as in id 16860, but remains unchanged as an alert for that id is not on that date.

After trying this:

```
r_id = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['id']
r_dates = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['date']

df['tdelta'] = np.where((df['id'].isin(r_id) & df['date'].isin(r_dates)),250,df['tdelta'])
```

The below shows an incorrect output:

```
   reset category       date     id  group  tdelta  tdelta reverse
6      N      low 2021-06-23  16860    2.0    33.0             0.0
5      Y      low 2021-05-21  16860    2.0   250.0           -33.0
10     N   medium 2020-12-06   1111    1.0   250.0             0.0
1      Y      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0   250.0             0.0
2      N      low 2020-12-06  16860    1.0   250.0             0.0
8      Y   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0   250.0           -29.0
9      N   medium 2020-11-07   1111    1.0   250.0           -29.0
4      N      low 2019-11-08  16860    0.0    65.0             0.0
3      N      low 2019-09-07  16860    0.0     3.0           -62.0
7      N   medium 2019-09-04   1111    0.0     0.0             0.0
0      N      low 2019-09-04  16860    0.0     0.0           -65.0
```

Comment: tried numpy.where ?

Answer (score 1):

Timing of your apply():

```
In: %timeit df['tdelta'] = df.apply(format, axis =1)
Out: 11.3 ms ± 470 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Last time I've measured apply it was without

```
df['id'] == row['id']
```

my bad, now I understand what it's for.

To make it faster, we'll need 2 lists:

```
r_id = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['id']
r_dates = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['date']
```

Updated numpy.where:

```
df['tdelta'] = np.where((df['id'].isin(r_id) & df['date'].isin(r_dates)),250,df['tdelta'])
```

generating each of these lists was about half of np.where time for each, all together (generating lists and numpy where:)

```
1.63 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[223, 227, 2214, 2215, 226, 2215, 2215, 238, 253],
    'reset':['N','Y','N','Y','N','Y','N','Y','Y'],
                   'date':[3, 7, 15, 16, 15, 15, 15, 38, 53],
                   'tdelta':[3, 7, 14, 15, 17, 26, 32, 38, 53]})
r_id = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['id']
r_dates = df[df['reset'] == 'Y']['date']
df['tdelta'] = np.where((df['id'].isin(r_id) & df['date'].isin(r_dates)),250,df['tdelta'])
df
```

out:

```
    id  reset   date    tdelta
0   223     N   3       3
1   227     Y   7       250
2   2214    N   15      14
3   2215    Y   16      250
4   226     N   15      17
5   2215    Y   15      250
6   2215    N   15      250
7   238     Y   38      250
8   253     Y   53      250
```

Comment: Since OP specifically asks for a "more efficient" method, it would be helpful to OP and future readers to provide some basic benchmarking.

Comment: and that's how you motivated me to learn %timeit...

Comment: How would this take into account the id column if I do not use the apply() method? each id has a unique set of alerts and so I had to create reset_group to take this into account

Comment: if the above is incorrect pls, give an example

Comment: So the code is significantly faster but the output is incorrect... I've put this new output into my edit...

Comment: so, in the new output the only issue is row with index 10?(should equal tdelta, instead of 250)?

Comment: yes, it should remain unchanged because that particular id does not have an alert on those dates

Comment: as in your index goes from 0 - 10, rather than what I have shown above?

Comment: I tried your df and it has the same result as you, perhaps the behaviour is different with dates rather than ints?

Comment: that's beyond me, the only thing I'd try is to reset index, so your output has index in order

Comment: tried resetting the index, I think there is an issue when trying to find equivalent dates.

Comment: have u tried converting dates to int and running it? just to make sure it's the date column?

Comment: @AdamKubalica it's not the date format, it's the two lists. Say id 226 also had another entry where reset is Y, this would also lead to that rows tdelta changing to 250...